# C#: get text and printing it with webdriver

Tags: c#, webdriver

I have this page: http://services.ce3c.be/ciprg/?countrys=ANGUILLA

I' m trying to get the text(country and IPs) and print it with:

```
var content = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"/html/body/pre/text()")).Text; 
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

but it seems that doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "/text()"
from the XPATH. You cannot point to text nodes in Selenium.

**This works:**

```
var content = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"/html/body/pre")).Text; 
Console.WriteLine(content);
```